# Page Not Found in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

Code in my Route file look like this :

```
Route::delete('/subtask1/delete/{{subtask}}', 'TaskController@subtaskdestroy');
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
    Route::get('/redirect/{provider}', 'SocialAuthController@redirect');
    Route::get('/callback/{provider}', 'SocialAuthController@callback');
});
```

Code in view file:

```
<form action="/subtask1/delete/{{1}}" method="POST" style="display: inline-block;">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    <button type="submit" id="delete-task-{{$subtask->id }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
    <i class="fa fa-btn fa-trash"></i>Delete
    </button>
</form>
```

And code on the Controller:

```
public function subtaskdestroy(Request $request, Subtask $subtask)
{
    $this->authorize('checkTaskOwner', $subtask);

    $subtask->delete();

    return redirect('/tasks');
}
```

With this code, I am getting an error like this:

`Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:`

Comment: Check to make sure that your route is registered as expected. Use `php artisan route:list | grep "subtask"` to see the registered routes. Also your route definition of `{{subtask}}` is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You mistake when defined route for delete. It should be like this:

```
Route::delete('/subtask1/delete/{subtask}', 'TaskController@subtaskdestroy');
```

But you given:

```
Route::delete('/subtask1/delete/{{subtask}}', 'TaskController@subtaskdestroy');
```

More about Route Parameters:

[Laravel Route Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#required-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You used `return redirect('/tasks');` in your controller. With this line the page will redirecte to route `/tasks` after successfully delete the data. Make sure you have `/tasks` route in your route file. Example:

```
 Route::get('/tasks','YourController@method');
```